# Android: TextInputLayout with one Edit Text and spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textinputlayout

I want to create a layout like this:
[image]

I want to add a spinner in TextInputLayout and show the hint of TextInputEditText like this.

I tried making custom TextInputLayout but still not able to add a spinner to it.

I have added TextInputLayout like this with outlined view:-

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorGreyView"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Mobile Number"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: So you can use horizontal linearlayout as a parent. And Spinner and text input layout both will be separated using weight property. You need to apply border background to that parent linrarlayout.

Comment: @Piyush But that doesn't allow hint to float. The hint that should appear as label hides away. I have already tried this.

Comment: Can you check [1](https://gist.github.com/paolorotolo/507339fce63d0698424b) and [2](https://github.com/ganfra/MaterialSpinner). Might be help

Comment: @Piyush both links are for single child. Both links are helping in adding a floating label for spinner,but there is no informatin regarding two nested child.

Comment: So instead of linear layout you can use relative or frame layout

Comment: @Piyush I tried but I am not successful to achieve the same. Can you share some snippet using relative or frame layout. The issue lies with the highlighted box and label.

Answer (score 0):

> implementation `'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08'`

Use `TextInputLayout ExposedDropdownMenu`alongwith EditextText and Try this:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Label"
        app:errorEnabled="true">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/filled_exposed_dropdown"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:editable="false" />

         <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**Adjust width sizes as per requirement.**

Comment: I tried the same dependency and the same style mentioned but xml is not able to parse the same. It is showing Binary XML inflate error while doing so

Comment: Try to use latest dependency to resolve style issue : implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08'